# Make different TreeSet maintaining the same order as another

Tags: java, treeset

Lets say i have a TreeSet that is naturally ordered. What interface and method can i use to make a new TreeSet maintaining the same order as the first list.

Comment: `Comparator` defines the ordering

Comment: Do you mean just `new TreeSet<>(oldTreeSet)`? (Doesn't even try to recompare the elements, so long as there is no `Comparator` on the old `TreeSet`.)

Answer (score 1):

Use the same `Comparator` (or `naturalOrder` if your elements implement `Comparable`):

```
class A implements Comparable<A> { }


final TreeSet<A> firstSet = new TreeSet<>();
final TreeSet<A> secondSet = new TreeSet<>(firstSet.comparator());
final TreeSet<A> secondSetNaturalOrder = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.naturalOrder());
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a TreeSet<> to do this.  You can use a LinkedHashSet<>().

```
       List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(List.of(10,3,2,2,1,20,40,2));

      Set<Integer> set1 = new LinkedHashSet<>();
      set1.addAll(list);
```

Except for deleted duplicates, the order is maintained.

```
      System.out.println("set1 = " + set1);
      System.out.println("list = " + list);
```

But for a `TreeSet`, the set is sorted by `natural order` of the objects.

```
      Set<Integer> set2 = new TreeSet<>();

      set2.addAll(list);
      list.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());
```

Again, the order is the same but sorted.  The `TreeSet` defaults to natural order sorting.
For `List.sort()`, the `comparator` had to be supplied.

```
  System.out.println("set2 = " + set2);
  System.out.println("list = " + list);
```